# Sorting based on currenttime from timezone in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

My requirement is to sort the station results based on current time in descending order. In station table i have a timezone column which holds values like this

```
--------------+
| timezone     |
+--------------+
| Etc/GMT+12   |
| Etc/GMT+11   |
| Etc/GMT+10   |
| Etc/GMT+9    |
```

Based on this column value i need to generate current time of each station and need to sort based on descending order of current time. Can any one please help me for this to work out?

Comment: you miss a bunch of information for your question: the table structure, the full set of the fields involved an example of the desired output and what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort by timezone (in this format), here are two methods.

If the "Etc" part is of fixed length, then:

```
order by length(timezone) desc, timezone desc
```

If the "Etc" part is of variable length:

```
order by replace(substring_index(timezone, '/', -1), 'GMT', 0) + 0 desc
```

You can extract the timezone offset and use this to change the local time to UTC.  You don't provide sample data for the "Etc" part, so I assume you know how to do this.

Comment: i think he has a UTC date and time and he is trying to calculate the local date and time for that UTC one based on the timezone field. And then to order the records based on the calculated field.